# Display domain information using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How can I display the domain, name and site (and nothing else) of all domain controllers using a single PowerShell command?

I've tried `Get-ADDomainController` cmdlet, but I only seem to get the local domaincontroller and not the information of my second server.

Comment: Looks more like a question for [su] or [sf]

Comment: The help for Get-ADDomainController actually has an example on how to do this, except for selecting your desired properties. This should do the trick `(Get-ADForest).Domains | %{ Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $_ } | select Domain, Name, Site`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$getdomain = [System.Directoryservices.Activedirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain() 
$getdomain | ForEach-Object {$_.DomainControllers} |  
ForEach-Object { 
  $hEntry= [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($_.Name) 
  New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{ 
      Forest = $_.Forest 
      Name = $_.Name 
      IPAddress = $hEntry.AddressList[0].IPAddressToString 
     } 
}
```

Source: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-List-of-Domain-4c993070